# ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN and automatic COLUMNS list

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I am looking to add a new column to table using the suggestions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599519/alter-table-add-column-takes-a-long-time/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186525/group-output-of-show-columns-into-comma-delimited-list/)

In essence, I would like the *(fields_in_orig_table)* to be populated automatically, and not having to enter them manually (have many columns and this changes from table to table):

```
CREATE TABLE games_new LIKE games_orig;
ALTER TABLE games_new ADD COLUMN location varchar(256);
INSERT INTO games_new (fields_in_orig_table) SELECT * FROM games_orig;
RENAME TABLE games_orig TO games_old, games_new TO games_orig;
DROP TABLE games_old;
```

My thought goes around this:

```
CREATE TABLE games_new LIKE games_orig;
ALTER TABLE  games_new ADD COLUMN version varchar(256);
INSERT INTO  games_new 

          (SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY ordinal_position 
           SEPARATOR " ,  "), " ") AS columns
           FROM information_schema.columns
           WHERE table_schema = 'games' AND table_name = 'games_orig' ) 

SELECT * FROM games_orig;
RENAME TABLE games_orig TO games_old, games_new TO games_orig;
DROP TABLE games_old;
```

This gives me syntax error (near the Select concat....).

The original syntax to get comma delimited column listings is:

```
SELECT CONCAT("'", GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY ordinal_position SEPARATOR "', '"), "'") AS columns
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' AND table_name = 'tbl_name'
```

In my query, I have removed the extra quotes, as I figure my query does not require quotes as part of the column listing.

What am I doing wrong here? Who could help, please?

Comment: If you set up an SQL fiddle it might be easier for us to help

Comment: Created SQL fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7a76e/3

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO  games_new 

VALUES (SELECT CONCAT....
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, still getting the same Error 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY ordinal_position SEPARATOR " , ' .....)

Answer (score 0):

When inserting values in the table use `INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (fields)` instead of `INSERT INTO tablename SET(fields)`.

```
CREATE TABLE games_new LIKE games_orig;
ALTER TABLE  games_new ADD COLUMN version varchar(256);
INSERT INTO  games_new 
          VALUES
          (SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY ordinal_position 
           SEPARATOR ' , '), ' ') AS columns
           FROM information_schema.columns
           WHERE table_schema = 'games' AND table_name = 'games_orig' ) 

SELECT * FROM games_orig;
RENAME TABLE games_orig TO games_old, games_new TO games_orig;
DROP TABLE games_old;
```

Comment: instead of double qoute, try using single quote only. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which column you want to insert into, because your nested query is returning only 1 value

```
INSERT INTO games_new (column_name_u_want_to_insert_value_into) 
SELECT   cast(concat(group_concat(column_name ORDER BY ordinal_position SEPARATOR " , "), " ") AS CHAR) AS columns
FROM     information_schema.columns 
WHERE    table_name = 'games_orig';
```

also, if you are running all the statements together, add semicolon(;) for the insert query as well

Comment: Is the Fiddle I created sufficiently built out?

Comment: I have got the result now that your code provides!

mysql> select * from games_new;
+------+-----------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| id   | game_name | year_issued | version                     |
+------+-----------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| NULL | NULL      |        NULL | id, game_name, year_issued  |
+------+-----------+-------------+-------------------

However - what I'd like is for the new table (games_new) to actually copy those actualy columns (ones that comes as the resulkt of the query), not to have the title of the columns listed in one cell.